# Send SSRS Report as attachment in an email

Tags: email, reporting-services

I want to send SSRS report as an email

I know you can create a subscription so report will be generated automatically and sent to a user, but this is not what i want
What I want is once user generates a report they can see a button to send the report as an email to any email address they want.

Something like Send email in Word or Excel.

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Where would you expect to see this button you refer to?

Comment: Near the "Save As" button. or any other way that can allows us to send a report as an email straight away.

Comment: What you want doesn't exist out of the box. The closest thing would be to export and open the report in Excel or Word, then email the report from that application.

Comment: Why can't the user download the report and email themselves to whomever they want?